# Is chaining in conditional statements idiomatic rust?

Tags: rust

Consider the following condition in a if statement, is there a more idiomatic, clean, or readable way to write this?

```rust
if some_path_to_text_maybe
    .extension()
    .and_then(|ext| Some(ext == "txt"))
    .unwrap_or(false) {
        // do something   
}
```

Comment: Questions like “Is X idiomatic?” are often opinion based, and those questions are off-topic for SO. The Rust Users Forum might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: I would add, sometime context is needed to know if a code could be write better. I don't think you question can be answer by a general answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is one line less:

```
if some_path_to_text_maybe
    .extension()
    .map_or(false, |ext| ext == "txt") {
        // do something   
}
```

Alternatively, you could try the two-step:

```
if let Some(ext) = some_path_to_text_maybe.extension() {
    if ext=="txt" {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but is it idiomatic? I don't think I usually see code written like this in the projects that I have looked over...

Comment: @allsey87 Good question. I admit that it took me a while to become familiar with `map_or`, but now I tend to use it in such situations.

Comment: @allsey87 There isn't the one right solution. When dealing with `Option`s, you often have a choice between `if let`, `match` or chaining `Option` methods, or a combination of the three. There is no convention what is "best". Use your judgment, and keep it simple.

Comment: The problem I have with `map_or` is that the arguments seems out of order to me. If only it were called `or_map`...